# Extended Kalman Filter and PID controller

Tags: pid, matlab, ekf

I'm trying to build a model based on tracking an object in 2-D using MATLAB (time-varying system).
I built the model using an **Extended Kalman Filter** and a **PID controller**.

I have a doubt regards the relation of the reference with. I think that it is a theoretical doubt but, after some research I still do not understand.

In your opinion what are the signal that must follow my reference?
The state ("real" position x and y) or the estimated state (estimated position x and y")?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know the true state (or at least the real position x and y)?

Comment: I know the initial position regarding x and y.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* marcck, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I was editing my question, but a great answer arrived. However I'll take into account these guidelines. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You always act on the estimated state, because if you knew the actual state then you wouldn't need an estimator!

Since you're in simulation, you could run the same test several times, running the PID controller with the real state one time and with the estimated state the other time. The results should be basically identical, and it's a good way to prove to yourself (and others!) that your estimator and complete system (estimator + controller) are working well.

I'll add though that you should run whatever tests you can with the actual system (step test, disturbance injection, etc.) and re-run the same tests against your modeled system. A great estimator and great controller don't really matter if your underlying model doesn't actually reflect reality!

Comment: You're right, thanks a lot!